# Emails are not firing in AWS server with some gmail account

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am using javax jar file to send the mails, Which is sending properly in local and which is not in aws server. and i tried some other gmail mail id in aws server , which is working fine. Do we need to do any settings in gmail account to trigger emails in aws server ?

Answer (score 0):

AWS take some security measures to avoid spam from being send from their EC2 instances, that is why you are not able to send emails. I don't fully remember but I think this can be solved by opening some ports on your EC2 instance, however the best way to send emails from AWS is by using SES.

Comment: It's not "opening some ports" on the instance.  It's using port 587 instead of port 25 to connect to Gmail.